# Warden authentication fail while overriding SessionsController from devise

Tags: api, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, warden

I have been trying to implement a SPA with Angular and API with Rails 4. I decided to use a session Controller to be inherited from devise session Controller for API and use warden for rack based authentication. Devise work fine till I log in, it redirect to dashboard page successfully however in API namespace session Controller I am not able to authenticate with warden.

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
before_action :warden_authenticate

def create
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  resource.create_authentication_token!
  render json: {authenticate_token: resource.authenticate_token}
end

def destroy
  sign_out(resource_name)
  resource.clear_authentication_token!
  render nothing:true
end

private

def warden_authenticate
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
end
end
```

When I curl with username and password

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/session -d '' -u abc@123.com:12345678

Started POST "/api/session" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-28 14:35:23 +0300
Processing by Api::SessionsController#create as JSON
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

It complain about csrf before which I fixed with in base Controller

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c|     c.request.format.include? 'application/json' }
```

Am I doing something wrong? I checked that warden is in list of middleware  after the session. When devise rollback its token_authentication I just wanted to have my custom token to be created every time user log in and send it through http header just for secure api. I am totally lost now.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the use of null_session on protect_from_forgery.  I can't imagine you could authenticate without a session to track the interaction.
Additionally, I would think about using a different base class for your API instead of putting the specific override of protect_from_forgery in ApplicationController.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @BrounoFacca the problem almost a year ago and I solved the problem by changing the devise gem version and it worked smooth. I almost bang my head for 7 days.